# int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Meeting'

Tags: python, django, django-models, tornado

Consider this function i am using Django along tornadoweb

```
def MeetingRecord(userid,mtngid,mesg):
    obj =  Usage()
    obj.name = userid
    obj.meeting_id = mtngid
    obj.action = mesg
  #  obj.participantid = participantid
    obj.save()
```

here is the model

```
class Usage(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('User',related_name = 'usage_user',null = True)
    meeting = models.ForeignKey('Meeting',related_name = 'meeting_usages',null = True)
    participant= models.ForeignKey('Participant',related_name = 'meeting_participant_id',null = True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now  = True)
    action = models.CharField(max_length = 500)
    miscellaneous = models.CharField(max_length = 500)
```

I am calling this method from a tornado class like

`MeetingRecord(check_user_exist,mtng,mesg)`

but i am getting following trackback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado-2.3-py2.7.egg/tornado/web.py", line 1021, in _execute
    getattr(self, self.request.method.lower())(*args, **kwargs)
  File "tornado_main.py", line 383, in post
    MeetingRecord(check_user_exist,mtng,mesg)
  File "tornado_main.py", line 503, in MeetingRecord
    obj.save()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.4-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/base.py", line 463, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.4-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/base.py", line 551, in save_base
    result = manager._insert([self], fields=fields, return_id=update_pk, using=using, raw=raw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.4-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/manager.py", line 203, in _insert
    return insert_query(self.model, objs, fields, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.4-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/query.py", line 1576, in insert_query
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.4-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 909, in execute_sql
    for sql, params in self.as_sql():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.4-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 872, in as_sql
    for obj in self.query.objs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.4-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 964, in get_db_prep_save
    connection=connection)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.4-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 292, in get_db_prep_save
    prepared=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.4-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 284, in get_db_prep_value
    value = self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.4-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 537, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Meeting'
```

I would like to confirm it that userid is the instance of User class and mtngid is the instance of meeting class .

Please help me out why i am getting this error .

Comment: Can you show your models.py for MeetingRecord?

Comment: Can you do:  print `userid`,`mtngid`,`mesg`, type(userid), type(mtngid), type(mesg)

I'm thiking that you're passing wrong data type somewhere, but stack log doesn't show the contents of your variables.

Comment: I already tried Jure here is my output User object  for print userid
Meeting object   for print mtngid
Meeting created successfully for pring mesg
<class 'models.User'> for  print type(userid)
<class 'models.Meeting'>for print type(mtngid)
Meeting created successfully for print mesg

Comment: "obj.meeting_id = mtngid" here you're probably passing a Meeting instance rather than a Meeting id.

Comment: @jpic should be right, try `MeetingRecord(check_user_exist,mtng.pk,mesg)`.

Comment: Fantastic, i added the comment as answer, please close the question so that other users can skip your topic when trying to find someone to help. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just an educated guess: "obj.meeting_id = mtngid" here you're probably passing a Meeting instance rather than a Meeting id.

Answer (score 0):

Your meeting is a foreign key, which expects an object, not the actual reference. You also don't have a `meeting_id` field.

Try this:

```
def MeetingRecord(userid,mtngid,mesg):
    obj =  Usage()
    obj.name = userid
    obj.meeting = mtngid
    obj.action = mesg
  #  obj.participantid = participantid
    obj.save()
```

You should also name your method's arguments appropriately.

Answer (score -1):

You used `obj.meeting_id` which is foreign key to Meeting' ID field ([AutoField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields)).
AutoField is [IntegerField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.AutoField). That's why error message says about **int() argument**. In your case you must use `obj.meeting_id = mtngid.id`. Burhan's way of object referencing is more clear. I only recommend to rename mtngid to mtng, because it's not id, it's object.